# How to implement Exo Player Extensions (Android Studio - JAVA )?

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, decoder

I'm trying to create an Video Player application with Exo Player (.
I implemented Exo Player but some videos need codecs (it plays without sound or video), but I don't know how to implement them.
I tried like this:
Copied Exo Player Extension folder to "my_project/app/Extensions"
and on my app build.gradle added this lines:

```
Implementation files('extensions/ffmpeg')
Implementation files('extensions/flac')
Implementation files('extensions/opus')
Implementation files('extensions/vp9')
```

But it does not work for Player Implementation I also imported Exo Player's (DemoUtil.java file)... but it does not work..
I read through internet someone gives ffmpeg.aar file, I tried to put ffmpeg.aar to lib directory then used code:

```
Implementation files('lib/ffmpeg.aar')
```

but I does not work, apps crushes when starts.

Can anyone help me how to implement this extensions in my project ?

Answer (score 2):

First, You need to follow the FFmpeg extensions step which is already provided by exoplayer :
[ExoPlayer FFmpeg extension](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/extensions/ffmpeg)

After the complete the above setup generate .aar from exoplayer root project using command :

> ./gradlew extension-ffmpeg:assembleRelease

Add generated .aar file in app level gradle

```
    implementation files('../libs/extension-vp9-release.aar')
```

Use FFmpeg with exoplayer

```
   val defaultRenderersFactory =
        DefaultRenderersFactory(context).setExtensionRendererMode(EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_PREFER)

    player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context, defaultRenderersFactory)
```